# Shopware 5: Error during import: No categories were found

Tags: shopware

At my trial
via Shopware backend > Contents> Import>

my_ANSI_categories_minimal.csv

default_categories_minimal (categories minimal)

and click on "import start" to import 
11 catechisms

I got the message: "Error importing No categories were found"

My my_ANSI_categories_minimal.csv
looks like:

categoryId, parentID, name
21.7, Irish

7 in found in phpmyadmin (SELECT * FROM `s_articles_categories_ro`)
the 21 is new / blank.

Shopware reports I should not use default import / export (* 1 no longer use the old default import / export ...).

How should I proceed then? Is there a nother import / export modul?
And why is this "import / export" Modul offered via the backend GUI?

BTW i use: Shopware 5.4.6 (Rev. 201807181357)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since shopware 5.3 the "advanced" module is part of shopware core. So you are alreay using the advanced module. The delimiter needs to be a semicolon (;) with a comma (,) it won't work at all. It is also needed that every parent category is created before its childs.

I created a test.csv with the following contents:

categoryId;parentID;name
21;7;test

This works fine in my tests. You can find the categories in the table s_categories .

Answer (score 0):

instead of

21.7, Irish

21; 7; Irish

write. This produced no error message.